# Dynamically Implementing Spring Security with Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to integrate Spring security into my DOM with dynamically created HTML? For example, display the button below only to users with ROLE_ADMIN:

```
var adminButton = 
    '<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" style="display:hide">' +
    '<a href="#">ADMINS ONLY </a>'                                     +
    '</div>'

$('#showButton').on('click', function(){
    adminButton.show();
}
```

This wouldn't be a permanent solution but it would be good to know if secure content can be handled through say an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

You mean displaying the button on click only if the user is admin? When `#showButton` is clicked you could ask the server, through AJAX, if the current session has such privilege. But why just not render the button only if the user is administrator?

Because the code for generating the button is still there, someone could inspect the JavaScript and easily bypass your check. In general is a bad practice to handle security aspects client side, what you usually do is only a first validation, in order to signal errors without the need to refresh the page, but every parameter of every action should be then validated server side.

In a case like this you do a double check. The first time when you generate (or not) the button, the second time in the code that handles the action the button triggers.